# C# IsNullOrZero

Tags: c#

This pattern comes up very frequently in my code:

```
x= x== 0? 1: x;
//or
x= x==null? 1: x;
```

However it happens that sometimes x is a long expression and I'd have to use intermediate variables. That's just useless boilerplate code. I can cook up a method and call it instead:

```
Util.IfNullOrZero(x, 1);
```

But that's just ugly. What is the best way of expressing the pattern? In ruby there is such syntax for **when x is nil** which gets rid of redundant x's:

```
x||= 1
```

I could extend `object` in a manner

```
public static class wtf
{
    public static T Default<T>(this object o, T d)
    {
        return o == null ? d : new object[] { o }.Cast<T>().First();
    }
}
```

And then do

```
object param= null;
int x= param.Default(1);
```

But that's a bit expensive.

In short how to best make C# do x||= 1 like in ruby?

**Update**

This is what I cooked up. I'm currently looking for a faster way of using the Template parameter to convert object to T.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static T d<T>(this object o, T d)
    {
        return o == null || o.Equals(default(T)) ? d : new object[] { o }.Cast<T>().First();
    }
}
```

In fact the code does three things at once: Casts to default type, checks for default value and also checks for null.

**Update 2**

```
return o == null || o.Equals(default(T)) ? d : (T)o; // much simpler and faster
```

I still think it is a commonality which needs to be included in core language.

**Update 3**
This is what I finally wrote, taking into account DataTable DBNull types.

```
public static T d<T>(this object o, T d)
{
    return o == null || (o is System.DBNull) || o.Equals(default(T)) ? d : (T)Convert.ChangeType(o, typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there anything like Or-Equals from Ruby in .NET/C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478082/is-there-anything-like-or-equals-from-ruby-in-net-c)

Comment: It's not exactly what you're looking for, but the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) (`x ?? value`) is the same thing as `x == null ? value : x`

Comment: You can't force a dog to become a cat - such operator simply does not exist - the answers in the dupe question are the best you can hope for. :)

Comment: If I were to post an answer suggesting to write an extension method, how many of you goons would downvote and claim that my code is "slow"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For checking for `null` and providing a default value, you can use the `??` operator:

```
return x ?? new Foo();
```

That means, if `x` is `null`, return `new Foo()`, else return `x`. You can use it for reference types and nullable types. For nun-nullable types like `int`, you still need to explicitly check for `0`.

Answer (score 4):

For handling the "==null" case, the null coalesce operator does the trick.

```
y = x ?? z;
```

means

```
if (x == null)
    y = z;
else
    y = x;
```

I'm not aware of something that check for both zero and null, writing a method to perform this task might be the best solution. Here it goes:

```
public static T IsNullOrZero<T>(this T variable, T defaultValue)
        {
            // defaultValue can't be null, doesn't make sense
            if (defaultValue == null) throw new ArgumentException("default value can't be null", "defaultValue");
            if (variable == null || variable.Equals(default(T))) 
                return defaultValue;
            return variable;
        }
```

Usage:

```
x = x.IsNullOrZero(y);
```

Note: this in fact works on non-numbers too (name might be misleading if dealing with non-numbers... maybe something along the lines of `IsNullOrDefault` might be a better name).

Comment: In fact, I grew fond of the idea and added this method to my "toolbox" project.

Answer (score 3):

You can check like

```
public static bool IsNullOrValue(this int? value, int valueToCheck)
 { 
    return (value??valueToCheck) == valueToCheck; 
 }
```

more on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633286/nullable-types-best-way-to-check-for-null-or-zero-in-c-sharp)

Comment: What about other numeric types ? This also does't handle the case when value is 0...

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the [Coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator (??), which does just that - if returns the first operand if it's not null, and the second if it is. This will instantiate a new object if the current one is null:

```
return myObj ?? new MyObject();
```

Note that the ?? operator works only for classes and reference types, not for ints and other value types that can't be null. There, you'll have to check manually for default, uninitialized values (0 for ints and shorts and stuff, false for bools, and so forth)